# Search for an image by pattern in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, search

I needed to use pictures of items from Minecraft for my project, but there are a lot of them for a long time to search and download, and I am very lazy. I got the idea to search Google for a picture using a template, for example: "minecraft: diamond_block" and the image must be on the domain: "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/" and must have an aspect ratio of 1: 1, these are the requirements that are needed to find the image I want. How do I implement this in NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

Used this

```
const GoogleImages = require('google-images');

const client = new GoogleImages('CSE KEY', 'API KEY');

const prefix = "minecraft "

let result = {}

client.search(prefix + 'ancient_debris', {})
  .then(images => {
    result = images.find((e) => {
      if (e.url.match("https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/") === null) return false
      if (e.url.match("latest") === null) return false
      if (e.url.match("smart") !== null) return false
      return e
    })
    console.log(result.url)
  });
```